# <select> reloads page when clicked on Opera Mini

Tags: html, css, opera-mini

Clicking on a `<select>` element with `border:none;` and `cursor:pointer` in Opera Mini reloads the page. Minimal example:

```css
select {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">English</option>
  <option value="2">Mathematics</option>
  <option value="3">Social Studies</option>
  <option value="4">Business</option>
</select>
```

Anyone knows a better way of fixing that other than removing one of these CSS properties or changing the border to `solid transparent 1px`?

Comment: Your minimal example needs to be included in the question. JSFiddle/JSBin links have never counted as including an example in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a `cursor: pointer;` [feature](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/#event-delegation-in-opera-mini). If you click on `pointer` area opera mini send page to server to run javascript event delegation.

> Event Delegation in Opera Mini
>
> Until recently,Event delegation didn’t work in Opera Mini. Now it’s
>   implemented by the Server sending clickable areas to the client for
>   anything with cursor:pointer. Delegation mostly works as expected with
>   click events with the exception of form elements; it’s rather hard to
>   detect whether using them should trigger an event (and thus a server
>   round trip) or not, unless an event listener is attached directly to
>   them. A workaround is to add a dummy event listener to required form
>   element.

Comment: Great, thank you! However, select works just fine with `pointer:click` as long as `border` is *not* set to `none`. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Oh, wait, it makes sense. Setting border to `none` makes `<select>` to loose it's "form element" status. The feature that you mentioned applies to all elements besides the form elements.